# Delayed Project

Tags: wine

I have a wine making kit, the must is for making an "old vine" zinfandel.  However, I purchased it just prior to moving and it was never opened and never make into wine. Would it be worth even trying to make it into wine now after more than 5 years sitting in the garage?

Answer (score 3):

As @brewchez says try make some wine with it, only thing I would additionally suggest is buy a new pack of yeast.

Answer (score 2):

It's always worth trying because it's always worth learning.  As long as you are willing to face the reality that it might get tossed out later.